# why can't I print all the headers (h1) from any site to python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
# https://nurseslabs.com/?s=heart+coma
searchp = {"s":"heart coma"}
searchpencode = urllib.parse.urlencode(searchp)
print(searchpencode)
url = "https://nurseslabs.com/"
url= url+ "?" + searchpencode
print(url)
openurl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
htmlcon = openurl.read(500)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcon,"html.parser")
# h1class="entry-title"
for i in soup.findAll("h1",{"class":"entry-title"}):
    print(i.a.text)
```

First I encode it, print it, then use the variable to go to heart coma after that, open url to print the html of the page then parse it. I did not print it because it will take place my problem that is the last statement does not print all the  that has class entry.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know what you want to do but i guess:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
#https://nurseslabs.com/?s=heart+coma
searchp = {"s":"heart coma"}
searchpencode = urllib.parse.urlencode(searchp)
print(searchpencode)
url = "https://nurseslabs.com/"
url= url+ "?" + searchpencode
print(url)
openurl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
htmlcon = openurl.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcon,"html.parser")
#h1class="entry-title"
for i in soup.select('.entry-title a'):
    print(i.text)
```

Prints:

```
s=heart+coma
https://nurseslabs.com/?s=heart+coma
18 Heart Failure Nursing Care Plans
3 Glaucoma Nursing Care Plans
Histamine-2 Antagonists
Normal Lab Values Reference Guide
Bronchodilators and Antiasthmatics
Nursing Care Plans (NCP): Ultimate Guide and Database
NCLEX-RN Cram Sheet for Nursing Exams (2019 Update)
13+ Diabetes Mellitus Nursing Care Plans
Computed Tomography (CT) Scan
Nursing Prioritization, Delegation and Assignment Quiz #4: Emergencies and Disasters (20 Items)
IV Flow Rate Calculation NCLEX Reviewer & Practice Questions (60 Items)
Drug Dosage Calculations NCLEX Practice Questions (100+ Items)
EKG Interpretation & Heart Arrhythmias Cheat Sheet
Nurse Salary 2020: How Much Do Registered Nurses Make?
Patient Positioning: Complete Guide for Nurses
Registered Nurse Career Guide: How to Become a Registered Nurse (RN)
NCLEX Questions Nursing Test Bank and Review
Nursing Theories and Theorists
```

and so on....